# Negative margin not working with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a grid layout with the help of the flexbox.

What I'm doing is that I'm giving parent negative margin on left and right and then giving its child the same amount of padding on left and right for the gutter space.

I'm trying to make 5 column grid and when I use `flex: 1 1 20%` all the columns are not coming in the same row. The last get wrapped in the next row. This should not be the case as `flex-basis` is set to 20% and parent should accommodate all five columns in one row.

But when I'm trying to do this, the 4th grid item is getting wrapped on the next line.

Here is the working codepen for this issue.
Updated the codepen: 
https://codepen.io/vikrantnegi007/pen/BZwGJQ

Thanks.

Comment: And when you just use `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.block`? All elements will be in the same row.

Comment: @Huelfe Yes box-sixing is not helping. I'm already using box-sizing.

Comment: Then your codepen is not complete. Cause when I add the snippet to your codepen, your elements will be in the same row.

Comment: With your codepen the `box-sizing` works. If it doesn't work in your own code, you need to provide a working code snippet that actually replicates the problem you encounter

Comment: Which bootstrap version do you use?

Comment: @LGSon Bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I add *bootstrap* to to [your codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyXVeZ) it works, which means you have some other issue we can't see in your original code.

*Note though, based on your image's settings, your elements still might wrap*

Still, instead of doing negative margin tricks, create a *gutter*, use `justify-content: space-around` and `flex-basis`.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgeoXw)

```
//testing css
.buisness-blocks {min-height: 250px;}

//main css
.buisness-blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .block {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 10px);
    outline: 1px solid;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative way to achieve the same layout. Thanks. 

But I'm still confused why didn't the negative margin worked because this librabry seems to use the same method. https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid/blob/master/dist/flexboxgrid.css

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 Can't say why your original doesn't work as I can't see it. Your codepen (with bootstrap) does. Have you tried to set your images to `display: block`?

Comment: Yes I did. Can you send you the zip of my code so you can have a better look at the full code? That will be grateful.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 Better if you simply give me a link. Parsing code take too long time

Comment: I've figured it out. The irregualr image sizes have caused the issue. When I made image all images equal it is working fine. tey using different dimension images. It get messed up.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 Lucky me then, as I have that in my answer as a note...now it will be easy to accept an answer :)

Comment: Check the updated codpen link. Why would the image sizes affects flex-basis ? Flex-basis should force images to reszie not the other way around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147620/discussion-between-vikrantnegi007-and-lgson).

Comment: This is a good solution to the original question. I would like to add that to use this technique in grid CSS, where you might have many different configurations (like Bootstrap), it may be simpler to use negative margins, as you only specify it in one place. When you use the pure flex-box solution, you will need to add the gutter calculation to every block size. (i.e. 50% - 10px, 25% - 10px, etc) This is easy to update when using a CSS aid like Sass, but in vanilla CSS it may be harder to maintain.

Comment: If using the left/right margins, you may want to then adjust the width to extend to make up for the shifting off to the left, plus the right padding (probably double the gutter.) On the container (with `display: flex`): `width: calc(100% + 20px); margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px;` Then on your flex item(s): `flex-basis: 50%` That way you can create a bunch of rules at different sizes and not have to do a calc() call.

Comment: @NeilMonroe Then you have to provide a solution that shows how that will actually work, as with the suggested CSS in your last comment, it won't work on the given question code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Is `box-sizing` the CSS property you are looking for?

Giving the `block`'s a `box-sizing` of `border-box`, they all come next to each other:

```
.block {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZeQjO

Comment: I'm using bootstrap so box-sizing is already there. This doesn't work with my code in the actual code.

Comment: `flex: 2` overrides the `flex-basis: 20%` with `flex-basis: 0`. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0):

Just Try This hope its work

```
.buisness-blocks {min-height: 250px;}


.buisness-blocks {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;

  .block {
    flex: 0 1 20%;
      -webkit-flex: 10;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 10;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: 2;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid;
  }
}
```

CLICK HERE for [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q8wcu5ah/)

Comment: because of the flex-wrap property specifies whether the flexible items should wrap or not.

Comment: I think you got the solutions.
Happy Codding Bro :)

Comment: No, I just noticed that you have removed the -ve margin that is why it is working. Your solution would not work with margin.

Answer (score -2):

If the negative margins aren't working with display flex, you can try to use transform:

At the CSS style properties of the inner element add the transform translate that you want.

Example:

```
transform: translateY(15px);
```